# How to remove "Paragraph" from "Format Select" for Joomla 1.5 jce editor

Tags: joomla, formatting, joomla1.5, joomla-content-editor

I am using JCE editor instead of the default tiny-mce. I am trying to customize the formatting interface for my users.

Is there a way to pull "Paragraph" out from the "Format Select" drop down list and create a custom standalone button just like "Bold" or "Underline"?

Something like this...

[image]

Comment: Back in 2011, questions for "_joomla peeps_" were best posted on Stack Overflow.  Since 2014, there is a dedicated place to post Joomla questions -- [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to edit the content of the Format list. In JCE 1.5 go to "Groups", select the "Editor Parameters" tab, go to the "Editor Options" area and remove the "p" (as in paragraph) from the list of  "Format Elements".

But actually this is not what you wanted. To create an extra button for the P format you might try some Javascript to convert the Format select into a sequence of buttons.

In JCE 1.5 in the JCE Plugin Manager, there is a button "New Plugin". That helps with setting up new plugins. In JCE 2.0 you will need to create a complete installation package first.